# Make my Style specific to a single instance

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

My wpf application has this Style:

Xaml:

```
<Style x:Key="customTableViewDataRowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type xcdg:DataRow}">
```

C#

```
this.Resources.Add(typeof(DataRow), this.FindResource("customTableViewDataRowStyle"));
```

It modifies the look of a Row in an Xceed Datagrid.

This all works great!

But I went and added another Xceed Datagrid to my app and it is using the style too.

Is there a way to not have it do that?  Can I make it only affect specific grids?

Comment: Are you referencing this style anywhere in your XAML o code? I don't see how a Named Style (having an x:Key) is applied to any elements without being referenced explicitly.

Comment: @HighCore - you are right.  I added the Code Behind that adds the style to all DataRows in all grids.  Do you know any way I could get that on only one DataGrid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could seperate the style into a standalone ResourceDictionary and then reference the ResourceDictionary only in the desired DataGrids.

Example with two DataGrids an only one of them have the style set:

CustomDataGridStyles.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
        <!-- Other Style Settings -->
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Window:

```
<Window x:Class="SpecificControlStyle.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <DataGrid Grid.Row="0">
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <ResourceDictionary>
                    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                        <ResourceDictionary Source="CustomDataGridStyles.xaml" />
                    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                </ResourceDictionary>
            </DataGrid.Resources>
        </DataGrid>
        <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: That did it.  Thanks!  As a side note for anyone else that finds this answer, I had to update my code behind to reference my grid (by name), rather than the whole window.